# Angular 6 *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor

I have 2 set of code in which one work and other doesn't. I need to know why?

**Not Working:**

```
<p *ngFor="let recp of recipes">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recp.name}}</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recp.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <img src="{{recp.imagePath}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:50px;">
            </span>
        </a>
        <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error: Cannot read property 'name'of undefined.**

**Working:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" 
        *ngFor="let recp of recipes">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recp.name}}</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recp.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <img src="{{recp.imagePath}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:50px;">
            </span>
        </a>
        <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this works if you think the issue is with the `<p>` tag,

```
<p *ngFor ="let arr of addIncrement;>{{arr}}</p>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the `<p>` element

Comment: *This means that `name` or `recp` is undefined* - Captain Obvious.

Comment: I think that you wanted to use *ngFor on div not on p.

Comment: @Antoniossss Updated the question

Comment: @D.Simon tried but got the error saying the tag is already closed. So left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to MDN, only phrasing content is allowed within a
>
> element. Angular might be enforcing that rule more than your browser
>
> P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements

Check this for more Info:

World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)  https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check for `null` (or) `undefined` before interpolating it. You can use the `?` to in such cases like this,

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recp?.name}}</h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recp?.description}}</p>
```

Hope this helps!.